# Avoiding the users to be able to see a directory in php

Tags: php, apache, security, directory

I currently working on a shop web application which I'm implementing with PHP.
According to our business model we need to have some pictures for every good that has been added to the system.So I've stored all of images in a folder that I call _goods_imgs . In this folder I've create a new folder for every good and stored their images in  it , and when I want to show the images to users in view_goods I use their absolute paths . My question is **how can I limit the access to this folder** so that if anyone types myshope.com/_goods_imgs in the browser can't be able to see the directories .
 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can suggest you @Umair 's answer, put an empty index.html file in every directory, so the directory tree won't show up to the users if they enter the absolute path.

Comment: To be honest , I have tried that way , but since I have a folder for each good in _goods_imgs directory , I've had to put an index in every single one , and I don't think that would be a good practice.

Comment: Joomla modules/components/plugins work that way. (justsaying)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Create a .htaccess file in your root folder and put the following code
>
> Options -Indexes

Comment: I've couple of questions ,1- Does it need any htpasswd file with it ? 2- since I've embeded images in html docs , is it going to allow theme to show in final html?

Comment: This is the only correct answer. No need for a htpasswd file. Just an .htaccess file with this Option. It will tell the webserver (Apache) to disable the folder listing.

Answer (score 1):

Inside every folder, put an empty or any `HTML` file named `index.html`

so whenever you will enter the path to the image folder, `index.html` will run instead of listing images in the folder

Answer (score 0):

I would put index.php file in it with following code

```
<?php
header("location:../");
// so every time user type that directory it will redirect to upper directory
// or you can put homepage address. 

?>
```